# How can a compiled Visual Studio Test Project be run & results monitored without the IDE installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, automated-tests

I'd like to copy a compiled Visual Studio Test Project (assemblies) to a target machine and run everything from there without having a license for Visual Studio on the target machine (note: only .net framework is installed on target machine).

Considering Test Projects are compiled down to IL dll code I don't see it a big stretch to run them on another machine except maybe for the **GUI** which shows the test results: it seems tightly integrated with the Visual Studio IDE.

I'm looking for visual output of the results without installing VS IDE, or at least to see test results without shelling out $$$ for another VS licence to only run tests.

Comment: What will you use to run the tests without an MSTEST license?

Comment: @JohnS: You might be onto something here (by hinging on gap in my knowledge). Do you know if MSTest can be split away from VS, and/or does it require payment?

Comment: I don't know. I do know there's a Visual Studio Team Test edition. Besides that, I suspect it's licensed as part of VS.

Comment: Why not convert the tests to NUnit or xUnit and free yourself from the licensing and installation issues? See http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=xunit&title=Comparisons

Comment: @TrueWill: I'm highly considering it after seeing the Microsoft options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run MSTest test on another machine with the [Gallio testrunner](http://www.gallio.org/Default.aspx).

You create a buildscript that uses the Gallio MS Build Task and run it with MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally [found some talk about mstest's existence distinct from VS (in 2005)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94215/include-mstest-in-the-net-framework-sdk) but it doesn't appear to have happened yet. Summary is:

request

> **Include mstest in the .NET Framework SDK**
>
> "*mstest should be included in the
> .NET Framwork 2.0 SDK so that unit
> tests created using Visual Studio Team
> System can be executed on test
> enviornments where VSTS cannot be
> installed.*"

response

> **Posted by Microsoft on 9/20/2005 at
> 7:34 PM** Thank you for your suggestion
> Brian. Unfortunately it is too late to
> do this for the current release (2.0)
> of the .NET SDK, but we will make sure
> to push for this in the next release.
> regards Hari Sekhar
> haris@microsoft.com .NET Framework SDK

**Update 1**: Through other answers, I've learned Microsoft makes available a version of Visual Studio test tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Test & performance tools which will install beside and inside each Visual Studio IDE.

I you do not like to install Visual Studio IDE, just Run VS setup and then just select the Persormance & test tools. This tool only needs .net Framework and then will provide a heavy test &performance tool with charting and analyzing component

[ Update by jdk: From comments, [link to Microsoft Visual Studio Test Professional 2010 RC – ISO](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MicrosoftDownloadCenter/~3/CGID4eZMMRc/details.aspx) ]

Comment: Which version of VS supports it?

Comment: as this tools dows not dependency on VS edition (and you can install it without vs soVS does not need to support it) - butif youmean in whichVS setup you can find it, I should say, VS 2008.

Comment: Dear JDK, I found direct VS Test tool which available at microsof                   thttp://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MicrosoftDownloadCenter/~3/CGID4eZMMRc/details.aspx                   you can download and install it, note that, it doesn't depend on VS and can install single.